# Launching Instance Store backed AMI in VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, vpc

I have created a `Instance Store backed AMI` from which I am able to launch IS backed instances in `ec2-classic` network. This suits my purpose as I am ok with data not persisting and it saves my `EBS` storage costs too.

Now We are trying to migrate to `VPC` and I am trying to launch `spot-instances` using my previous IS backed AMI in the `VPC`. So far I have tried to launch `m1.small` and `m3.large` but the spot request status shows "`cancelled`"  after "`pending for fulfilment`" state.

Are we allowed to launch IS backed instances in VPC?  I can not see anywhere in documentation where it says we are not allowed to so I am hoping we should be. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, this should work. Have you tried launching as On Demand rather than Spot, just to confirm that the Instance Store-backed AMI works? Then, try launching an m1/m3 Spot instance with a normal AMI to confirm it works for you. Then, try m1/m3 spot with your Instance Store-back AMI. A `cancelled` status is defined as "You cancelled the request, or the request expired".

Comment: Thanks for your response. It worked when I tried the second time. Probably I messed up the settings somewhere when trying for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can run `m1.small` and `m3.large` in VPC with ephemeral storage. For m1.small you AMI should be PV (para-virtualized).

Your spot request was not fulfilled because of insufficient capacity in certain AZ or region.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  It worked when I tried second time.